# Action Bar Library 4.0.2 with "SupportActivity cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Thanks in advance for looking at this. I am a little over my head with this one.

I have an android project that utilizes the Action Bar Sherlock compatibility library. I was able to run it fine with an older version ~3.5 which included its own android.support.v4 library with the additional class called "SupportActivity."

I accidentally updated the Sherlock library to its most recent version (4.0.2) which gets rid of the android.support.v4 source files and just uses a jar file. However, this jar file makes no reference to the "SupportActivity.class" and for some reason, my project now has this error:

```
   The type android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity cannot be resolved.
   It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
   LoadMapTask.java     /ncas/src/viiad/task    line 65 Java Problem
```

What's interesting is that this error falls on a comment line.
The code for "LoadMapTask.java" can be viewed [here](http://codepaste.net/1zruke).

Because it is "indirectly referenced," I can't find any instances of SupportActivity referenced anywhere in my project.

I am currently using Eclipse Indigo, compiling with Google APIs version 15 (4.0.3), and using the sdk/extras/android/support/v4/ jar. My build path also has Action Bar Sherlock (which compiles just fine) as a required project.

Let me know if you need any more information. Comments or help of any sort are deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock v4 uses `SherlockActivity` and `SherlockFragmentActivity`. You can find more information about using it [on the website](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reverting to an older version of the Action Bar Sherlock (3.5). If I wanted to use 4.0 or later, I would probably have to use methods from SherlockActivity or SherlockFragmentActivity in my code. Currently, that is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Since ABS updated to v4, `SupportActivity` is gone, just use `android.app.Activity`.

And use `SherlockActivity` and `SherlockFragmentActivity` to replace the android one.

You'd better check more [notes](https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts/cUSpT1tHRHk) from Roberto if needed.